# What causes the error "Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm."?

Tags: python, django

I see a lot of answers as to how to solve this issue, but I'd like to know what exactly causes this? I have a random password generator that generates a random sequence consisting of uppercase letters, lowercase letters and numbers like this:

```
min_char = 10
max_char = 12
allchar = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
genpassword = "".join(choice(allchar) for x in range(randint(min_char, max_char)))
```

This causes the "Invalid password" error and I'd like to know why.

Comment: What is the traceback? None of this code relates to passwords explicitly. It cannot possibly throw an "invalid password" error by itself.

Comment: Are you saving those passwords in the database?